# How to use cookie-based authentication with SignalR?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, authentication, websocket, signalr

I've an Asp.Net Core web API with an angular frontend.

Some cookie based authentication has been setup and work fine. In the asp.net controllers, if I try to access to `HttpContext.User`, it is properly filled.

Here is a bit more info on how it is configured:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
        {
            opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = tokenSettings.ValidIssuer,
                ValidAudience = tokenSettings.ValidAudience,
                IssuerSigningKey =
                    new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenSettings.SecurityKey))
            };
        });
```

and then:

```
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

Without entering in too much details, basically, it uses asp.net core identity framework to identify and authorize.

I also need to validate that the user has the right to open a signalR websocket(I've one by type of ressource).

So I override the `OnConnectedAsync` of my Hub:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    string dashboardId = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["dashboardId"];
    string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    await _mediator.Send(new StartDashboardDataAcquisitionCommand(Context.GetHttpContext().User, Guid.Parse(dashboardId)));

    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

My command handler then verify that the provided user has the expect permissions for this data.

My issue is that the User is basically empty at this point.

Here is how I initialize it on the client side:

```
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(environment.backendUrl + 'dashboards/data?dashboardId=' + dashboardId)
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .build();

this.connection.on('SendDashboardData', dataBatch => {
  this.store.dispatch(new SetActiveDashboardData(dataBatch as DataBatch));
});
this.connection.start().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

What am I missing? Why don't I get the HttpContext populated? I tought that since the token was stored in an cookie, the browser would anyway send it?

Comment: OK I see the JWT authentication handler configured, where is the cookie part of this?

Answer (score 0):

Just because the DefaultAuthenticateScheme is not correct

I tried with `services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application");` and succeeed

[image]

For your requirement

```
I also need to validate that the user has the right to open a signalR websocket
```

You could add the `[Authorize]` Attribute on the method ,you could check more details in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

And I recomend you to try with `Context.User` instead of `Context.GetHttpContext.User`